# Android custom textview with bluetooth device name

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I want to make a custom TextView java class which shows the name of the currently connected Bluetooth device. I want to use it in XML like `<com.me.me.BluetoothName`. Can someone help me?

I also could use a Custom view. But I don't know how to make a Custom View class to use it in XML.

Comment: Can you explain that with a little more context?

Comment: i would like to create one java class, which extends a TextView. In this Custom TextView class i want to get the Bluetooth Device name of the current connected BT Device. And when i use it in a Xml layout (example: "<com.me.me.BluetoothNameTextView") it woll show the name of the current connected bluetooth device. like "JBL Xtreme 2".